# batch-rename all config file endings to conform to apache 2.4

Tags: files, rename

Since Apache 2.4, all files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and `sites-enabled` have to be named with the ending `.conf`

Now on my server I have a lot of these files, renaming the files in `sites-available` is easy:

```
for i in /etc/apache2/sites-available/*; do 
  if [[ $i != *.conf ]]; then
    mv -v $i $i.conf; 
  fi
done
```

But how can I rename all of their links in `sites-enabled` with one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needing only one command is a hard thing to achieve with [unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Program_Design_in_the_UNIX_Environment) in mind.

On the other hand: you can rule major parts of your world using one-liners.

First fix the configuration files in `sites-available` with the script from the question,  then use the following code to create new symlinks in `sites-enabled`.

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
find . -type l -ls \
| awk '{print $13 ".conf -> " $11 ".conf"}' \
| mmv -s -n
```

This uses your existing links and creates new ones with `.conf` appended to both, source and destination.

`mmv -n` is the *dry run* that only shows what would have happened.  If you are satisfied with the results,  run again without `-n`

Then after you've run mmv without -n,
 remove the old dangling symlinks with

```
find -L /etc/apache2/sites-enabled -type l -delete
```

Comment: Only tested it short in my laboratory directory.  Why does not work for you?  I knew that the output of `mmv -n` can be used as input for another `mmv`,  so I made awk produce something that looks equal.

Comment: Unlike `ln -s`, `mmv` won't let you link objects that don't exist.  Try to omit the `.conf` after `$13` in the awk program.

Comment: Be aware, that this script only works, if you have no symlinks in sites-enabled that already end with `.conf`

Comment: One of the things I like about `mmv`: everything is checked before stupid deeds are done.  Do you think I should add this to the answer?  The output of `mmv` is quite self-explanatory IIRC.